# Programmatically changing backup file path of a Back Up Database task on SSIS

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, database-backups

I have an SSIS package which only includes one task: Backing up of a database. I can change the database to be backed up programmatically (C#) without any problems by changing the connection to be used and/or the connection string. The problem arises when I want to change the location of the back-up file: It seems like I cannot define variables for that purpose and my google search yielded no fruitful results about how to change the "backup file folder" value of the task programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try this solution.

1. Drag and drop a **Foreach Loop Container** and define a collection with paths where the backup files will be saved
2. In the **Variable Mappings** tab define a variable which will hold a location for a backup file
3. Place a **Back Up Database Task** inside of the **Foreach Loop Container**.
4. Go to the Properties of the **Back Up Database Task**, open the Expressions window. Choose a **DestinationAutoFolderPath** and in the expression window use the previously define variable.

Done.